# Who is Trip referring to by "zombie robot back from the dead"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In "*Turn, Turn, Turn*" (Season 1, Episode 17 of Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.), shortly after Trip and Simmons find out about Hydra from Agent Weaver we get this exchange:

> **Simmons**: How do I know I can trust you?
>
> **Trip**: Because I'm trustworthy. You're the one who works with a zombie robot back from the dead.

Who is Trip talking about here?

The obvious answer is Coulson, however that doesn't make sense since Trip doesn't know that Coulson had actually died at this point (since he wasn't Hydra, Garrett wouldn't have told him, and from his tone in Episode 14 after Ward says Coulson died to get the Bus it's seems pretty clear that he doesn't believe that).

Is he referring to Skye instead?

Comment: Isn't Coulson **famously** dead after Loki stabbed him?

Comment: http://agentsofshield.wikia.com/wiki/Michael_%22Mike%22_Peterson ?

Comment: Deathlok seems the obvious reference but SHIELD isn't working *with* him at this point

Comment: But what makes Coulson a *robot*? He doesn't have his robotic hand at this point.

Comment: @Adamant He's somewhat robotic in demeanor; inhumanly unflappable under most circumstances.

Comment: @Paulie_D Whether Coulson is considered "famously" dead as far as other SHIELD agents are concerned isn't really ever made clear - no agent we meet (in Season 1 at least) shows any surprise that Coulson is alive when meeting him, suggesting that either the story of his death isn't well known, or that anyone who *had* heard about his death just assumed it was faked.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's stated that the fact that he died is classified information, and the fact that he isn't dead is even more highly classified.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's been a while since I last watched this episode, I think the zombie robot in question is **Mike Peterson/Deathlok**. After being given the Centipede Serum by HYDRA, he was recruited by SHIELD to assist them in various matters. On one mission featuring the titular agents of SHIELD (Season 1, Episode 10, "The Bridge") he goes after the people behind the Centipede Serum, and is ultimately caught in an explosion and presumed dead. Later in the season, he is revived as Deathlok, a cyborg weapon of HYDRA, thereby fitting both the zombie and robot parts of the question.